# ANSI standard of UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

Tags: sql, mysql

UNIX_TIMESTAMP() isn't an ANSI standard keyword but an addition to the MySQL syntax. However, since I'm supporting multiple DB's, is there an ANSI standard way to write UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, no.

Every database handles this differently.

For example, in Oracle, you have to manually generate the timestamp with something like:

```
SELECT (sysdateColumn - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400) AS alias FROM tableName;
```

In MSSSQL:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, yourDateColumn, '19700101') AS alias FROM tableName
```

In PGSQL:

```
SELECT date_part('epoch', timestampColumn) AS alias FROM tableName
```

**Edit:** as [AlexKuznetsov pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061220/ansi-standard-of-unixtimestamp/1061408#1061408), there are two totally different usages of MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function. I assumed the latter, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` (for native format to epoch conversion) for the above answer.

Comment: MSSQL actually has a GETUTCDATE() function.

Comment: @Eric, from what I can remember, GETUTCDATE() in MSSQL still returns a DATETIME type.

Comment: @jason: So does DATEADD(). In this case, you need DATEDIFF, not DATEADD.

Comment: @me: GETUTCDATE() returns UTC time, and has nothing to do with a UNIX timestamp. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to define UNIX_TIMESTAMP
If the following is true:
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00'

then use DATEDIFF function